# Changes made in admin page not reflecting in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model to store info about following a profile. But when i'm following a profile in admin section[Through "Follow" table], it's not reflecting in the Profile table. When i'm following a profile in admin section[Through "Profile" table], the changes were not updated in "Follow" table.

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name = 'followed')
    bio = models.TextField(default='')
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    @property
    def num_follows(self):
        return self.followed.all().count()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

FOLLOW_CHOICES = (

('Follow', 'Follow'),
('Following', 'Following'),

)

class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follow_value = models.CharField(choices= FOLLOW_CHOICES,default='Follow', max_length=10)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.profile)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile, Follow

admin.site.register(Profile)
admin.site.register(Follow)
```

views.py:

```
def follow_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_id = request.POST.get('profile_id')
        profile_obj = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)

        if user in profile_obj.followed.all():
            profile_obj.followed.remove(user)
        else:
            profile_obj.followed.add(user)

        follow, created = Follow.objects.get_or_create(user=user, profile_id=profile_id)

        if not created:
            if follow.follow_value == 'Follow':
                follow.follow_value = 'Following'
            else:
                follow.follow_value = 'Follow'

        follow.save()
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'profile'))
```

html logic:

```
<form action="{% url 'follow-profile' %}" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="{{ post.author.profile.id }}">
              {% if user not in post.author.profile.followed.all %}
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" type="submit">Follow</button>
              {% else %}
                <button class="btn btn-info mb-4" type="submit">Following</button>
              {% endif %}
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation does not indicate that ManyToMany is using `Follow` model. So change the model definition like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Follow")
```

Also, [as shown in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models), you can use `InlineAdmin` for `Follow` model instead of registering it directly. For example:

```
class FollowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Follow
    extra = 1

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (FollowInline,)

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, i did't know this earlier. I have implemented as above but got new issues. Now, unable to unfollow through application.Tried debugging but unable to proceed further. able to do it from admin site.

Comment: If you are using through, then the implementation of M2M will be bit different. Please see the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships